# Is spin/rotation a unique and lonely euclidean function?

Tags: operator-theory, euclidean-geometry, euclidean-algorithm

Is there something more complex than a 2 dimensional "spin"? I wouldn't know how to describe it. We can spin 3 dimensional objects in 3 ways, but we can only spin them on an axis. All spins happen on an axis.
Is it possible for a higher-dimensional spin function to exist? Would it "rotate" around a plane?
Is this at all related to the Casimir operator?

Answer (score 0):

One can spin three dimensional objects in a lot of ways, but it is true that infinitesimal rotations are linear combinations of rotations along $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes. It is true that in three dimensions, we can only spin along an axis. This is related to the fact - which you should prove- that every element of $SO(3)$ has an eigenvector with eigenvalue $+1$. This eigenvector provides the acts of rotation. The existence of this eigenvector is forced by the fact that we are working in an odd number of dimensions. But, in dimension $4$, we could certainly have a "rotation" (an element of $SO(4)$) that is not rotation along an axis in the three dimensional sense. For instance, you could perform rotations in two disjoint planes separately. This would have no real eigenvectors, and so cannot be a rotation about any axis.